VotingRegressor not improving model score
I am currently trying to get a little bit into machine learning and experimenting with different models.
I have a problem to get a VotingRegressor to work. The metric used here is the r2 score.
E.G. the following code is resulting in a metric of -89:
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor

linear_model = LinearRegression()
xgb = XGBRegressor()
cat = CatBoostRegressor(verbose=0)
ridge = Ridge()

ensemble_model = VotingRegressor(estimators=[('linear_regression', linear_model), ('xgb', xgb), ('cat', cat), ('ridge', ridge)], weights=[1, 1, 1, 1])

y_pred = ensemble_model.predict(X_test)

r2 = r2_score(y_test.values, y_pred)

print(f"R² Score: {r2}")

While only using a linear Model is returning a 0.85:
linear_model = LinearRegression()
linear_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = linear_model.predict(X_test)

r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

print(f"R² Score: {r2}")

Would really appreciate some help here :)
Thanks in advance!
